# how to extract digits from a string?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

i have a list

```
a=['invoice β invoice # 2018-33167-2 β date 03/21/2018 β total due $8,804.90']
```

i want to extract only digits from this list of the form

```
a=['2018-33167-2 03/21/2018 8,804.90']
```

i have used regex to extract

```
for i in a:
  res = re.sub("\D", "", i)
```

but the result is

```
res=201833167203212018880490
```

Comment: Your expected output does not contain only digits... Please clarify your question.

Comment: Essentially you want something that starts with a digit, anything in the middle except a space, and ends with a digit

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extract-numbers-from-string/ see this can help you.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extract-digits-from-given-string/

Comment: Maybe try this regex. `\d[^ ]+\d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected output, you want more than just digits. The digits can have `/`, `-` and `,`.

Maybe, perhaps, you wanted something that starts with and ends with a digit, but anything in the middle other than a space?

```
import re
a='invoice β invoice # 2018-33167-2 β date 03/21/2018 β total due $8,804.90'
print(re.findall(r'\d[^ ]+\d', a))
```

output

```
python3 test.py
['2018-33167-2', '03/21/2018', '8,804.90']
```

Comment: we can unlist `a` in the function: `re.findall(r'\d[^ ]+\d', *a)`